# Rails3 Arel Building the Where Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I'm trying to build the where clause using AREL but this does not execute the query:

```
 rec = self.where('color' => color_passed)
 rec = rec.where('make' => make_passed) if make_passed.present?
 rec = rec.where('year' => year_passed) if year_passed.present?
```

How can I correctly append the where conditions based on some conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean not execute? `where` only return a Relation object, you have to call `all` to get the result:

```
rec.all
```

Comment: That works. I thought I didn't need to do .all since it works when I don't do all that appending. New to AREL. Coming from rails2.